# How do I concatenate a string with a literal inline and without spaces using bash?

Tags: bash

Suppose I have this:

```
MYSTR="hello"
```

And now I want to generate some command using `$MYSTR` and some literals, but I **don't** want a space after "hello", suppose I want to extract a file called `/tmp/helloworld.tar.gz`:

```
tar -xzf /tmp/$MYSTRworld.tar.gz # this won't work...
```

Can I do this without having to concatenate `hello` and `world` together separately?

Comment: put the path inside double quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use var separator in shell i.e. `${var}`:

```
tar -xzf "/tmp/${MYSTR}world.tar.gz"
```